# Bootstrap Long list in Drop down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Bootstrap dropdown elements are overflowing.

You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/Banzay/5dcontvb/3/

I can't use height, like below as this pushes other elements to have that height too:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Many Thanks,

Youssef

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you dont necessarily want to use "height" property since not all lists are going to be long.  you want to use max-height so it can be shorter as well. 
Also, use the overflow-y:auto to set up a scrollbar if necessary
[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dcontvb/5/)

```
.dropdown-menu {
    max-height:400px;
    overflow-y:auto;    
}
```